# How can I use es6 syntax to import sip.js library

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sip

I keep getting errors when trying to import sip.js library to my project, I have installed it via npm

```
npm install sip.js --save
```

I have tried, but kept on getting errors.

```
import { SIP } from 'sip.js'
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Jonasw how is this about general computer software and hardware?

Comment: _"I keep getting errors"_. Like what? What's your environment? Etc...

Comment: import errors that is "can't find module ..etc"

Comment: It works for me, although there isn't an export called `SIP` so I'm using `import * as SIP from 'sip.js'`.

Comment: yup, that did it! thanks

Answer (score 3):

The correct Syntax would be:

```
import * as SIP from 'sip.js'
```

credits to @robertklep

Comment: I have tried the latest version and getting this error using above statement sip.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'SIP')
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (sip.js:46:15)
    at sip.js:47:3

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```js
import { Web, URI } from 'sip.js';

const { SimpleUser } = Web;
```

https://github.com/onsip/SIP.js/blob/master/src/index.ts